# Linearizing this absolute difference objective function $\min\sum_{i=1}^{I}\sum_{j=1}^{i}|x_i-x_j|$

Tags: linear-programming, modeling, linearization

For $x_i>0, i=1,\ldots,I$, I tried to linearize this objective function
$$\min\sum_{i=1}^{I}\sum_{j=1}^{i}|x_i-x_j|$$
as
$$\min\sum_{i=1}^{I}\sum_{j=1}^{i}y_{ij}$$
subject to
\begin{align}
& y_{ij} \le x_i-x_j \quad i=1,\ldots,I, j =1,\ldots,i\\
& y_{ij} \le x_j-x_i \quad i=1,\ldots,I, j =1,\ldots,i\\
& y_{ij} \ge x_i-x_j + M(1-z_{ij}) \quad i=1,\ldots,I, j =1,\ldots,i\\
& y_{ij} \ge x_j-x_i + Mz_{ij} \quad i=,\ldots,I, j =1,\ldots,i
\end{align}
and $z_{ij}\in\{0,1\}, \forall i=1,\ldots,I, j =1,\ldots,i$.

Is this linearization correct? Is there a way to avoid $M$-constraints to avoid computational problems?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As you are minimizing $y_{ij}$, it is sufficient to use
$$
y_{ij} \geq x_i - x_j \quad \forall i, j \\
y_{ij} \geq x_j - x_i \quad \forall i, j
$$